# Drawing hourglass with user input for symbol and size

Tags: java

I have been working on a self study task and i can't seem to get this right, if i try to print an hourglass using the code below. Still learning.

```
public class test
{
    public static void hourglass(int size, char symbol){

        for(int i=size-1;i>=1;i--){

          for(int j=i;j<size;j++)

              System.out.print(" ");

          for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++)

              System.out.print(symbol);

              System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i=2;i<=size-1;i++)
        {

         for(int j=i;j<size;j++)
             System.out.print(" ");

         for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++)

             System.out.print(symbol);
             System.out.println();

        } 

    }
}
```

it will print 3 perfectly:

[image: output for 3]

if i try to print it with numbers 5 and 7
**5:** 
[image: output for 5]

and then **7:** 
[image: output for 7]

How would i go about correcting this?

Comment: I'm a little confused. What does size signify, and why are the other hourglasses incorrect?

Comment: well for the other hourglasses if i specify 5 its supposed to print 5 lines of A to draw the hour glass but i get 7 lines of A top to bottom and the same goes for 7 where i get 11 lines of A instead of 7

Comment: I edited your question to remove the new question. You should _try_ to implement it, then ask another question if/when you're unable to find a solution after researching.

Comment: @CarrieKendall should i then create a new post for the new question because BitNinja answered this one

Comment: I'd say first you should research and if you're unable to find existing resources then ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code and found something interesting. If you notice in your incorrect hourglasses there is an extra row of "A"s on the top an bottom. This must mean that the loop is running too much. If we look at your first loop

```
for(int i = size - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
```

Specifically the declaration part, we see that it starts at `size - 1` this only works for a height of 3. Well, `Math.floor(size / 2) == 1` where `size == 3`.

We can see a similar situation in the second main loop.

```
for(int i = 2; i <= size - 1; i++) {
```

This time the `size - 1` part is in the conditional part of the loop.

So the solution is easy, all we need to do is declare a variable and subtract in the two aforementioned parts of the loop with it. I call the variable "subtract" but you can call it whatever you want.

```
int subtract = (int)Math.floor(size / 2);
```

Then instead of subtracting 1 we just subtract `subtract`.

First loop:

```
for(int i = size - subtract; i >= 1; i--) {
```

Second loop:

```
for(int i = 2; i <= size - subtract; i++) {
```

This will make it work correctly. Remember that this will only work for even values of `size`.

Comment: i have a question going to edit my original question

Comment: @RyanD1987 You should just ask a new question.

Comment: ok when i print to console there are spaces to the left of the hourglass how do i get rid of them

Comment: @RyanD1987 I mean completely [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question. :)